# Shopping Cart Offers

Tags: algorithms

I have been wondering about this issue for quiet some time now. I find interesting and I have not been able to come up with a solution.

This must be seen in a context of a shopping cart where you can first choose to add 1 gold bar to your cart and then add another 2, so the sum is 3.

Let's say we have these products:

1 gold bar = 40$
2 gold bars = 80$
3 gold bars = 110$

So when I add 1 gold bar, my cart is 40$ dollars worth. Adding another 2, then my cart is 120$ worth.

Now I have 3 gold bars in my cart.

But there is a price for 3 gold bars at 110$, and I want that price to kick in of course, because I do have 3 gold bars in my cart.

Can this be categorized as a normal knapsack issue ? Or are there any other way of looking at it ?

Thank you

Comment: Research *bulk pricing* or *volume discounts*. Possibly related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2569534/algorithm-to-price-bulk-discounts

Comment: Why the downvotes ? If you can't answer the question at least leave it open for a while so others may have a shot at it.

Answer (score 0):

I agree it sounds like dynamic programming.
BTW the question phrasing doesn't say how you wanted to approach some edge cases, e.g.

1. There could be a few combinations of deals to "cover" the shopping cart, e.g. if the cart has 6 bars, and you have a special discount for a bulk of 3, and a different discount for bulk of 4, you should see what's cheaper: two deals of 3 (6=3+3) or one deal of 4 while the remaining 2 are without discount (6=4+2).
2. Sometimes, buying *more* ends up cheaper or the same, and as a customer I saw humans/sites that would note "hey, you might as well get another one, it'll be cheaper".

I saw this discussion:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3495916/minimize-price-for-volume-discount-orders 
(also there is a more generalised problem of "internet shopping problem", but I think it's an overkill if you're really just running one site which has a small number of deals).